# PhoneGap FileReader/readAsDataURL Not Triggering Callbacks

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, filereader

I am using PhoneGap Build to build an iOS v7.1+ application and using [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/) to debug. I am using the media-capture plugin and file API to capture a video in an attempt get its base64 representation. I can get the video recorder to open, take a video, and return the file path. I then use `resolveLocalFileSystemURL()` to get a file object which `readAsDataURL()` requires. The problem is `FileReader` is never calling the `onloadend` callback.

I have been poking around all day. Putting `console.log()`'s everywhere I could think of. I checked to make sure the iOS version [is supported](http://www.caniuse.com/#feat=filereader). Every variable is what I expect yet the callback is simply not being called. I have also tried setting up all the other callbacks but none of them ever get called, either. I have tried replacing `readAsDataURL()` with `readAsText()` but I still get bupkis. I have tried waiting up to five minutes since I figured an asynchronous call may take a bit but still nothing.

Below is my code. Below that is the console output.

```
var elements = new Object();
elements["video"] = $("#window_incident_create > .video > source")[0];

navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(
    function(files) {
        for ( var i in files ) {
            var file = files[i];

            var name = file.name;
            var path = file.fullPath;
            if ( path.indexOf("/private") === 0 )
                path = "file://" + path.substr(8);
            else
                path = "file://" + path;
            var type = file.type;
            var lastModifiedDate = file.lastModifiedDate;
            var size = file.size;

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function(event) {
                console.log(3);
                elements["video"].type = type;
                elements["video"].src = "data:" + type + ";base64," + event.target.result;
                console.log(4);
            };

            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
                path,
                function(entry) {
                    console.log(1, entry.nativeURL);
                    reader.readAsDataURL(entry);
                    console.log(2);
                },
                function(error) {
                    console.log("0-0", error);
                }
            );
        }
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("0-1", error);
    },
    {
        limit:  1
    }
);
```

> 1 "file:///var/mobile/Applications/AB239984-FB9F-43C0-B699-3596AC8A43A8/tmp/capture/capturedvideo.MOV"
>
> 2

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Reorganize your code a bit. Put the `reader` initialisation and `onloadend` callback inside the `resolveLocalFileSystemURL` success callback.

Something like this:

```
var elements = new Object();
elements["video"] = $("#window_incident_create > .video > source")[0];

navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(
    function(files) {
        for ( var i in files ) {
            var file = files[i];

            var name = file.name;
            var path = file.fullPath;
            if ( path.indexOf("/private") === 0 )
                path = "file://" + path.substr(8);
            else
                path = "file://" + path;
            var type = file.type;
            var lastModifiedDate = file.lastModifiedDate;
            var size = file.size;

            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
                path,
                function(entry) {
                    console.log(1, entry.nativeURL);
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onloadend = function(event) {
                        console.log(3);
                        elements["video"].type = type;
                        elements["video"].src = "data:" + type + ";base64," + event.target.result;
                        console.log(4);
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(entry);
                    console.log(2);
                },
                function(error) {
                    console.log("0-0", error);
                }
            );
        }
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("0-1", error);
    },
    {
        limit:  1
    }
);
```