# readAsDataURL does not process file from captureAudio

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor

My FileReader object is working perfectly to upload images. I'm tracking `onload` as well as other events, these all happen when I upload images:

```
fileReader = new FileReader();

fileReader.onloadstart = (e) => {
  window.alert('fileReader onloadstart');
  window.alert(e);
};

// ... and the same for onprogress, onabort, onerror, then finally:

fileReader.onload = (e) => {
  window.alert('arrived to fileReader.onload!');
  // ...
};
```

I added `cordova-plugin-media-capture` to capture audio. I now need to use the existing `fileReader.onload` callback to upload it etc.

But no matter what I do, I cannot get `fileReader.readAsDataURL` to respond. Below is my code adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29192327/get-base64-of-audio-data-from-cordova-capture) about a similar problem, but it doesn't resolve it.

None of the `fileReader` events are firing, not even error. The `fileReader.readAsDataURL` function is available, yet when calling it all that happens is the screen briefly goes white and then I'm back at the page I was at before as if I had not done anything. None of the methods on `fileReader` show their alerts.

```
  navigator.device.capture.captureAudio((files) => {
      const file = files[0];
      newFile = new File(
        file.name,
        file.localURL,
        file.type,
        file.lastModifiedDate,
        file.size);

      window.alert(newFile); 
      // --> [Object object]

      window.alert(JSON.stringify(newFile));
      // --> An object with name, localURL etc. See image.

      window.alert(fileReader.readAsDataURL);
      // --> function readAsDataURL() { [native code] }

      fileReader.readAsDataURL(newFile); // nothing at all
  })
```

The stringified `newFile` object is:

[image: newFile stringified]

I've tried processing the file `captureAudio` gives in different ways:

- `resolveLocalFileSystemURL`: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/80/how-to-convert-a-image-from-the-device-to-base64-with-javascript-in-cordova
- `fileSystem.root.getFile` as in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/phonegap/uX_aDRKp72I/ZUbt0ThWVQkJ

But every time the same thing: when I arrive at `readAsDataURL`, nothing happens anymore. What could be wrong?

Edit: I forgot to mention some things:

- tested on iOS device and simulator
- cordova-plugin-file is installed

Comment: Please try installing this one as well: cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file

Comment: The project already included `cordova-plugin-file`, sorry I forgot to mention it. Thanks @NielsSteenbeek, do you have any idea what else may be wrong?

Comment: Maybe copy-paste my example 1:1 and see whether onload is invoked. If that works, you can encapsulate in a promise.

Comment: Thanks @NielsSteenbeek! It turns out defining a new FileReader solves the problem. I still don't understand why I cannot access the existing one... even copying over the existing `onload` to the new one works fine. But well, it works. Thanks a lot!